# ValueError: "<InternalDocument: тест>" needs to have a value for field "attachmentowner_ptr" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python-3.x, django

структура моделей следующая:

```py
class AttachmentOwner(models.Model):
    attachment_owner_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class ProcessObjectOwner(models.Model):
    process_object_owner_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

Document(AttachmentOwner, ProcessObjectOwner):
    ...

InternalDocument(Document):
    ...
```

view, в котором я пытаюсь создать объект InternalDocument:

```py
InternalDocumentsUpdateModelView(UpdatePermissionMixin, UpdateModelView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ...
        status = int_status.under_consideration.name
        valid_addressees = [i for i in coaddressees.forms if not
        i.cleaned_data['DELETE']]
        user = get_delegate_or_user()
        delegation = get_current_delegation()
        draft = self.object
        for i, addressee in enumerate(valid_addressees):
            cleaned_addressee = addressee.cleaned_data['coaddressee']
            document = InternalDocument.objects.create(content=draft.content,
                                                  addressee=cleaned_addressee,
                                                        implementer=draft.implementer,
                                                               approved=draft.approved,
                                                               status=status,
                                                               nomenclature_of_deal=draft.nomenclature_of_deal,
                                                               text=draft.text,
                                                               addressee_subdivision=cleaned_addressee.subdivision,
                                                               content_type=ContentType.objects.get(
                                                                   app_label='documents',
                                                                   model='internaldocument'),
                                                               cipher=draft.cipher,
                                                               creator=user,
                                                               date_of_create=datetime.datetime.now(),
                                                               organization=draft.organization,
                                                               subdivision=draft.subdivision,
                                                               grant_to_all=draft.grant_to_all)
```

здесь coaddressees - формсет
и тут на месте InternalDocument.objects.create происходит краш

```bsh
Internal Server Error: /documents/internaldocuments/37/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\important\work\edms-2\edms\src\edms\apps\documents\views\internaldocument.py", line 304, in post
    return self.form_valid(form, **data)
  File "C:\important\work\edms-2\edms\src\edms\apps\documents\views\internaldocument.py", line 356, in form_valid
    grant_to_all=draft.grant_to_all)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 568, in __init__
    _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 513, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 830, in __init__
    (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
ValueError: "<InternalDocument: тест>" needs to have a value for field "attachmentowner_ptr" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
[20/Jun/2019 12:56:08] "POST /documents/internaldocuments/37/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 130603
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено, не заметил что при создании было одно поле m2m.